# Hiding password text immediately Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've got an `EditText` in my `.xml` file as a password. 
 
If i type in there it shows the most recent character for a few seconds. 
Is it possible that the text will be hidden immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to `setTransformationMethod` to your `edittext` like this:

```
editText =  findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
editText .setTransformationMethod(new TransformationMethod());
```

Don't forget to create the `TransformationMethod` class similar to this:

```
public class TransformationMethodextends  {

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PassCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PassCharSequence implements CharSequence {

        private CharSequence charSequence;

        public PassCharSequence (CharSequence charSequence) {
            this.charSequence= charSequence; 
        }

       public int length() {
            return charSequence.length(); 
        }


        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '.'; 
        }


        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); 
        }
    }
};
```